# Запятые в предложении: "Теперь(,) конечно(,) неважно, какой она была"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

1.Теперь, конечно, неважно, какой она была.
2.Теперь, конечно неважно, какой она была.

Подскажите, какой вариант правильный?

Answer (score 6):

Вводное слово "конечно" находится в середине первой части сложноподчинённого предложения. Обособляем вводное слово запятыми: *Теперь, конечно, неважно, какой она была*.

Вводные слова не обособлятся, если находятся в начале или в конце обособленного оборота. Ср.:  ***Оставьте вы эти новые доводы, неубедительные и надуманные конечно.*** (пример отсюда: [Когда вводные слова не выделяются запятыми](https://7lafa.com/pageanswer.php?id=44189).  Если вводное слово находится в начале оборота, заключённого в скобки, то оно отделяется запятой:
*Оба сообщения (по-видимому, поступившие недавно) привлекли к себе широкое внимание* (там же).

В нашем случае обособленнных конструкций нет, только вводное слово. Запятую ставим по обычному правилу обособления вводных слов.

Comment: Как-то неуютно мне, если обособленный оборот распространенный, а вводное слово в его конце не отделено от оборота. Нет ли уточнений на этото счет?

Comment: Давайте возьмём предложение из ответа "Оставьте вы эти новые доводы, неубедительные и надуманные конечно." Если поставить запятую перед "конечно", то появится двусмысленность: вводное слово относится к предложению до обособления "неубедительные и надуманные" (Оставьте вы эти новые доводы,.. конечно) или к обособлению "неубедительные и надуманные" (неубедительные и надуманные, конечно).

Answer (score 1):

Слово "конечно" следует выделить запятыми как вводное.

**Теперь, конечно, неважно, какой она была.**